# Powershell on 2012 PrintServer searching for printer port with certain subnets

Tags: powershell, split, ip-address

I am interning at a company and we need to redefine our client's printer IP schema. I'm fairly green with powershell and I am using Powershell ISE and when I use:

```
    Get-PrinterPort
```

I get the full list as expected. However, if I am looking for any printer ports within the subnet set of 192.168.228.*, I have used the following:

```
    $IPAddress = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | Where-Object ({$_.Name.Split('.').index[-1]} -eq '228')
    $IPAddress = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | Where-Object ({$_.Name.Split('.')} -match '192.168.228*')
    $IPAddress = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | Where-Object ({$_.Name.Split('.').index[-1]} -match '228')
```

Nothing will display. I have tried many variations of the -match, -icontains, -contains, -like and several others that will search for the partial IP address

```
    $IPAddress = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | Where-Object ({$_.Name.Split('.')} -match '*228')
```

I have also modified the script to:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -OutVariable allIPs
  foreach ($splitIP  in $allIPs -split '.' ){
    $splitIP = $allIPs -split '.'
    sort $splitIP[2] -Unique -OutVariable uniqueSubnetIP
    }
    $uniqueSubnetIP
```

[This is the output I get from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT5J0.jpg)

Ultimately, I want to filter through each of the subnet IPs and locate the ones where the last octet are outside the schema and automate a process to put them in range like this:

```
< 192.268.***.50 || > 192.168.***.60
```

Any help you can offer is really appreciated; I've spent days trying to figure this out.

Comment: I just realized on the first part I didn't give a command to display anything, so it does exactly what I told it to do; I just didn't tell it to show me it did anything.

Comment: So.. this question is no longer relevant?  If so, you can close it - it's near the edit options.

Comment: Only the first part was no longer relevant, the lower portion is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't consider `$printerport.name` to be reliable for detecting subnets; use `$printerport.hostaddress` instead.

`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort | Where-Object {($_.HostAddress -split '\.')[2] -eq 228}` appears to return the printerport objects in the subnet you want - for a different subnet, just change the `228` to whatever the appropriate value is.

The `-split` operator takes a regular expression, so the `.` must be escaped, `\.`. The operation will result in an array of four items, representing the octets of the IP address of the port. The third octet is in `@()[2]`; you can test other octets similarly by changing the `[2]` to `[0]`, `[1]`, or `[3]`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I can't believe I have spent so many hours on such a simple solution! This works just as I need it to. Follow up question... If I wanted to automate the search by setting the 3rd octet as $subnetOct and using that variable to go through the 20+ subnets and perform the >||< comparable on the 4th octet, what do you think would be the best solution for that?

Comment: That's an awfully broad followup question. There are many ways to do it; the question is going to be which fits best for your processing, and only you can decide that.

The way I'd most likely do it would be to assign the third-octets to an array (e.g., `$thirds = @(228, 241, 243, 250)`) and then iterate over the array by wrapping your processing in a foreach block (e.g., `foreach ($octet in $thirds) { ... }`, substituting `$octet` for `228` in the original response).

Comment: If you find that an answer solves your original problem, please accept it.